# Getting an error when using mkdir in powershell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am trying to use mkdir in PowerShell with this command

```
mkdir -p ~/.jitsi-meet-cfg/{"web/letsencrypt", "transcripts", "prosody/config", "prosody/prosody-plugins-custom", "jicofo", "jvb", "jigasi", "jibri"}
```

I have tried this solution [Getting an error while creating multiple folders using `powershell` command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/1083255/getting-an-error-while-creating-multiple-folders-using-powershell-command-line) but I keep getting this error

```
mkdir : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '"web/letsencrypt", "transcripts",
"prosody/config", "prosody/prosody-plugins-custom", "jicofo", "jvb", "jigasi", "jibri"'.
```

Where did I go wrong? I am using windows 10

Comment: when in powershell, `mkdir` is a PoSh function, not the BAT/CMD command. take a look at `Get-Help mkdir` and you will see that it is a wrapper for `New-Item` that is specific to making dirs. [*grin*] then take a look at `Get-Command -Name mkdir -Syntax` for how it is used. next, if you get interested, take a gander at `(Get-Command -Name mkdir).Definition`.

Comment: as it said on the question you linked, `mkdir "web/letsencrypt", "transcripts", "prosody/config", "prosody/prosody-plugins-custom", "jicofo", "jvb", "jigasi", "jibri"` works